# React map nested array within object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The goal is to pull in the nested array "records". My current output displays the array within the react console, but with an error. I will try and be as concise as possible but will keep things short.

The error screen has 3 lines that are referencing _getRecords so im positive that _getRecords is the problem child.

```
class RecordBox extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();

  this.state = {
    showComments: false,
    results: []
  };
 }
 render(){
   const records = this._getRecords();
   return (
      // jsx template code...
   );
  }
  // API Call
 _fetchRecords() {
  $.ajax({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'http://apidata:8888/data.json',
   success: (results) => {
     this.setState({ results });
   },
   error: () => {
     console.log('error');
   }
  });
 }
 _getRecords() {
    // TypeError: this.state.results.map is not a function...
    return this.state.results.map((record) => {
      return <Comment body={record["Contractor Name"]} />
    });
  }
}
```

I have a feed that looks like the below. I do not have permission to modify this.

```
{
"result": {
  "records": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "clu.hey@gmail.com",
      "author": "Clu",
      "Contractor Name": "Just say no to love!!",
      "avatarUrl": "https://placeimg.com/200/240/any"
    },{
      "id": 2,
      "email": "hello@gmail.com",
      "author": "Anne Droid",
      "Contractor Name": "I wanna know what love is...",
      "avatarUrl": "https://placeimg.com/200/240/any"
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

[image: REACT Console]

Comment: why is _getRecords outside class?

Comment: What are you storing in `this.state.results` and when?

Comment: @arkjoseph How do you call _getRecords and from where?

Comment: did you bind.(this) to the _getRecords function?

Comment: let me know if that last edit helps.

Comment: Yes that helps,now it appears that when you feed the data to results, you are doing some error at that point

Comment: Can you tell me how do you feed the data to results inside this.state?

Comment: @arkjoseph the problem is with the way you are feeding data to your component.I tried the same code with dummy data and it works.

Comment: @VivekN - the api call _fetchRecords is now added. Can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: According to the state image you posted the call should be 
this.state.results.result.records.map

Comment: @arkjoseph check the answer that I have posted.It should solve your problem.

Comment: both answers are correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _fetchRecords function needs to change to:-

```
_fetchRecords() {
  $.ajax({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'http://apidata:8888/data.json',
   success: (results) => {
     this.setState({ results: results.result.records });
   },
   error: () => {
     console.log('error');
   }
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just aren't setting the state to the right thing. Your *state.results* is currently an object. Just make sure when you set your state, you set *state.results* to *results.result.records*

```
this.setState({ results: results.result.records })
```

One thing you could also do is map the results directly in the jsx code and skip using the _getRecords function.

```
<div>
   {
     this.state.results.map( ( record ) => {
       return <Comment />
     }
   }
</div>
```

This is the way I usually write this as it's easier for me to read, but it's personal preference.

I hope this helps!